# How to insert a username into a post in meteor

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, meteor-accounts

I want to insert the username along with the post. When I tried adding a post using `Post.insert({content: content})` the post got inserted and displayed on the client successfully. Now I try to insert a username also, so I try like this:

```
var username = new Meteor.user().username;
Post.insert({content: content, username: username});
```

Now not only the username not inserted it fails to insert the content as well. No error. What am I doing wrong?

The above is the problem. But I did a mistake and deleted insecure package so now I can not check the results from console or inserting directly at client. So the following is the method I used. (Please be patient, I'm new to meteor, if I ask stupid questions, pardon me).

In imports/both/post.js I put:

```
    export const Post = new Mongo.Collection('post');
```

In server/main.js

```
    import { Post } from '/imports/both/post.js';

    Meteor.methods({
    addPost: function (content) {
    var user = Meteor.users.findOne(this.userId);
    var username = user ? user.username : 'Anonymous';
    Post.insert({content: content, username: username});
     }
    });
```

In client/template/postsForm.js, the following code:

```
    import { Post } from '/imports/both/post.js';

    Template.postsForm.events({
    'submit form': function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var content = document.getElementById('content').value;
    Meteor.call('addPost', content);
    event.target.reset();
    }
    });
```

I can insert a post from server  and get displayed on client but from client side I can't. And I get no error.

Comment: Why are you using `new` before `Meteor.user().username`?

Comment: I'm following a tutorial and it was shown that way.

Comment: Could you link to that tutorial? zim's answer is most likely what you need

Comment: Please check the edited version and let me know what to do :)

Answer (score 0):

are you sure it's failing on the insert? you have a "new" in front of Meteor.user(), i suspect it's failing there. try the following, which includes a null check on the user and shows any error coming from the insert:

```
let username = Meteor.user() && Meteor.user().username;
Post.insert({content: content, username: username}, function(error) {
  if (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
};
```

you also have 'content' in quotes, which looks wrong.

Comment: Please check the edited version and let me know what to do :)

Comment: in your update, you said you can insert a post from the server, but not the client. i'm unsure what you mean "from the client." do you mean your call to the Meteor method is failing, or is that what you mean from the server? i don't understand.

Comment: I'm supposed to enter content from client side (in the browser), which is not working. But when I enter the content from server side, it gets displayed on the client side.

Comment: @Matt, yes, any data successfully entered should be published to the client and appear reactively. to enter data directly on the client, you need either 1) the insecure package installed, or 2) the allow/deny rules set up to allow it. c.f. https://guide.meteor.com/security.html#allow-deny

Comment: You mean like this:                                                                           Post.allow({
 insert() { return true; }
});       in   server/main.js ?

Comment: @Matt, yes, but that has to be in common code. otherwise the client will reject the attempt.

Comment: No change. I added the code before the addPost method. what else should I do?